# Search query using like with AND logic in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are using hibernate 3.6.3.Final and MySql database in my application. I need to transform the following Mysql query to HQL using java.

```
select * from user where name like "%mohan%" and name like '%ram%';
```

How to do this logical AND operator in hibernate and java??

Answer (score 1):

Edit :

You need to dynamically define an hql query:

```
String[] likes = {"foo", "bar"};

String myQuery = "select e from User e where 1=1";
for(int i=0; i<likes.length; i++){
    myQuery+= " and e.name like :"+i;
}

Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(myQuery);

for(int i=0; i<likes.length; i++){
    query.setParameter(i, "%"+likes[i]+"%");
}
query.list();
```

Note : you can use a StringBuilder to concatenate the strings

Comment: If I give a one or two parameter is possible, I have a string array then how do I do this?

Comment: in this case, you need to dynamically create the query, let me edit my post

Comment: Why do you put 1=1 in where condition??

Comment: Its not working... I am getting the following error... org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: you might need to wrap the whole thing into : session session = getsessionfactory().opensession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();      ----tyour code---- tx.commit();
session.close();

Comment: hibernate is a complex framework : I suggest you read some of the official documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/